# The meaning and definition of $\psi^{(-2)}(x)$, and the convergence of some related series involving the Möbius function

Tags: derivatives, convergence-divergence, mobius-function, polygamma, digamma-function

While I was playing with a CAS I find that makes sense the function $$\psi^{(-k)}(x),$$
for example $\psi^{(-2)}(x)$, where $\psi^{(n)}(x)$ denotes the $n$th derivative of the digamma function, see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html).

> **Question 1 (Answered see the comments).** Can you explain what is the function $\psi^{(-2)}(x)$? I am asking about what is its definition. **Many thanks.**

I think that maybe is a notation for the second antiderivative, but I would like to know a definition with rigor about what is previous function, and what is previous notation.

As a puzzle I wondered if it is possible to deduce the convergence of some series involving previous functions, and the Möbius function $\mu(n)$, see the definition of this arithmetic function from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html).

> **Question 2.** Can you deduce the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)\frac{\psi^{(-1)}(n)}{n^3}\tag{1}$$ or $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)\frac{\psi^{(-2)}(n)}{n^3}\,?\tag{2}$$
>   **Many thanks.**

Only is required to prove the convergence of some example in previous Question 2, well the first or the second series.

Comment: $\psi^{(-2)}(x)$ is no generally known mathematical notation, so if you want to ask about it, *you* define it, or refer to a definition. Otherwise, you risk your question to be closed for missing context (or not belonging to mathematics at all).

Comment: See for example Adamchik's paper ["Polygamma functions of negative order "](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377042798001927/1-s2.0-S0377042798001927-main.pdf?_tid=10281142-1eee-4371-b058-222eaff117e7&acdnat=1520585704_f4e633d4c37818bcc9f493ae4f154660)

Comment: Many thanks for the definition @RaymondManzoni

Comment: Many thanks @ProfessorVector

Comment: You are welcome @user243301!

Answer (score 2):

[WolframAlpha's definition](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/02/): "formula presents (not unique) continuation of the classic definition of $\psi^{(\nu)}(z)$ from positive integer values of $\nu$ to its arbitrary complex values... it is very convenient to use it as basic definition of polygamma function for any arbitrary complex values $\nu$, where symbol $\frac{\partial^\nu\psi(z)}{\partial z^\nu}$ denotes the $\nu$th fractional integro-derivative of $\psi(z)$ with respect to $z$ (which provides the Riemann-Liouville-Hadamand fractional left-sided integro-differentiation with beginning at the point $0$). Such approach was realized in *Mathematica*."

In essence, it would seem Mathematica's definition relies on taking the [fractional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral#Fractional_derivatives) of the log gamma function, with $\psi^{(-1)}(z)=\ln\Gamma(z)$. For negative integers, this would give

$$\psi^{(-k)}(z)=\int_0^z\int_0^{z_1}\dots\int_0^{z_{k-2}}\ln\Gamma(z_{k-1})~dz_{k-1}\dots dz_2~dz_1=\frac1{(k-2)!}\int_0^z(z-t)^{k-2}\ln\Gamma(t)~dt$$

One also happens to have the [special value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Integration_over_log-gamma) of

$$\psi^{(-2)}(z)=\int_0^z\ln\Gamma(t)~dt=\frac z2\ln(2\pi)+\frac{z(1-z)}2+z\ln\Gamma(z)-\ln G(z+1)$$

where $G$ is the [Barnes-G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).

Provided Stirling's approximation of the Gamma function, one can quickly see the first series converge absolutely, while the second sum converges conditionally since $\sum\mu(n)\ln n/n$ converges.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529205/evaluating-the-log-gamma-integral-int-0z-log-gamma-x-mathrm-dx-i).