# Expressions of G-BARNES

Tags: special-functions, polylogarithm, polygamma

All people know expressions G-BARNES FUNCTION for example G(1/2), G(3/2) etc ... or G(1/4), G(3/4).
But someone know G(1/8), G(3/8), G(5/8) or G(7/8) in terms of Psi(1,1/8) ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just funny that you wrote "All people know ..." - I honestly had to google the Barnes G-function :)

Comment: @MattiP. I was tempted to edit it, but figured it was more quaint that way. Here is [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950398/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi3x-log2-sin-frac-x2-dx) of the rather few occurrences of Barnes G-function in MSE. The function seems a bit exotic that even the notation and terminology (aka "double gamma function") needs caution.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/issac/issac01.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Closed-forms (in terms of other constants) of the *[Barnes G-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html)* $G(z)$ for fractional $z = \frac{p}{q}$ with $0<p<q$ are known only (for now) for **SEVEN** special values. Given the *[Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function)* $\operatorname{Cl}_2(z)$ and,

$$\begin{aligned}
A \;&= \text{Glaisher–Kinkelin constant}\\
\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi2\right) &=\text{Catalan's constant}\\
\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi3\right) &=\text{Gieseking's constant}
\end{aligned}$$

then,

$$\begin{aligned}
\ln G\left(\frac12\right) &= -\frac32\ln A -\frac12\ln\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)+\frac1{24}\ln 2+\frac1{8}\\
\ln G\left(\frac13\right) &= -\frac43\ln A -\frac23\ln\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)-\frac{1}{6\pi}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi3\right)+\frac1{72}\ln 3+\frac1{9}\\
\ln G\left(\frac23\right) &= -\frac43\ln A -\frac13\ln\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)+\frac{1}{6\pi}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi3\right)+\frac1{72}\ln 3+\frac1{9}\\
\ln G\left(\frac14\right) &= -\frac98\ln A -\frac34\ln\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)-\frac{1}{4\pi}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi2\right)+\frac3{32}\\
\ln G\left(\frac34\right) &= -\frac98\ln A -\frac14\ln\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)+\frac{1}{4\pi}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi2\right)+\frac3{32}\\
\ln G\left(\frac16\right) &= -\frac56\ln A -\frac56\ln\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)-\frac{1}{4\pi}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi3\right)-\frac1{72}\ln 2-\frac1{144}\ln3+\frac5{72}\\
\ln G\left(\frac56\right) &= -\frac56\ln A -\frac16\ln\Gamma\left(\frac56\right)+\frac{1}{4\pi}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi3\right)-\frac1{72}\ln 2-\frac1{144}\ln3+\frac5{72}\\
\end{aligned}$$

**That's all.** However, for *ratios* of Barnes G-function, we have,

$$\ln\left( \frac{G(1-z)}{G(z)} \right)= z\ln\left(\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi}
\right)+\ln\Gamma(z)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\operatorname{Cl}_2(2\pi z)$$

Since there's a relationship between $\operatorname{Cl}_2(m)$ and polygamma $\psi^{(1)}(n)$, one can indeed use $\psi^{(1)}(\frac18)$ etc to express the ratio $G(\frac78)/G(\frac18)$, but it is harder when numerator and denominator are taken separately.

---

$\color{red}{\text{Update, July 26}}$. From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2881946/4781), we find,

$$\psi^{(-2)}(z)=\int_0^z\ln\Gamma(t)~dt=\frac{z(1-z)}2+\frac z2\ln(2\pi)+z\ln\Gamma(z)-\ln G(z+1)$$

Since $G(1+z)=\Gamma(z)\, G(z)$ then,

> $$\qquad\color{red}{\psi^{(-2)}(z)} = \frac{z(1-z)}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln 2\pi -(1-z)\ln\Gamma(z) -\ln \color{red}{G(z)}$$

Thus, it is possible to express every Barnes G-function $G(z)$ in terms of the polygamma function, but one has to use negative order and analytic continuation.

Comment: [Here is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BarnesG%5B1%2F2%5D) $G\big(\frac12\big)$ in WA syntax.