# Boundedness of a sequence of sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence 
$$ x_k = \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{l=1}^k \left( \begin{array}{l}k\\l \end{array} \right) \left( \frac{k}{l}\right)^2,$$
where the first term in the sum is the binomial coefficient.

**Question:** Does this sequence converge or at least remain bounded?

I tried evaluating the limit with Mathematica without any luck. However, the numerical analysis below suggests that $x_k$ converge to a finite value (maybe 4?).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a comment, which contained the answer but seemed to have disappeared. Hence, I am posting this short answer myself.

In fact, one can use the approximating property of the Bernstein polynomials discussed in [this earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305329/binomial-analogue-of-riemann-sum-for-definite-integral) defining the function $f$ to be
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} x^{-2}, & x > \epsilon \\ \epsilon^{-2} & x \leq \epsilon \end{array} \right.$$
for some $\epsilon < \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer.*

I suppose that Mathematica gave as a result
$$x_k = \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{l=1}^k \left( \begin{array}{l}k\\l \end{array} \right) \left( \frac{k}{l}\right)^2=2^{-k}\, k^3 \,\, _4F_3(1,1,1,1-k;2,2,2;-1)$$ which, I suppose, you could have computed for very large $k$.

Let $k=10^n$; computing
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_{10^n} \\
 1 & 6.53390898912372 \\
 2 & 4.12641241484375 \\
 3 & 4.01206038296720 \\
 4 & 4.00120060038029 \\
 5 & 4.00012000600038 \\
 6 & 4.00001200006000
\end{array}
\right)$$ where you can see two nice patterns.